# jquery call for a remote php function

Tags: php, jquery, function, drop-down-menu

I have a selectbox that needs to be updated dynamically. I am using jquery to perform that using .load($url), where $url is the location of the php file to call. I am wondering if there is a way to call a specific function within that php file instead of calling the entire php file.

Comment: I don't believe there is, sorry. You are effectively opening a web page and capturing the output. I don't think there's anyway from a URL to cause a specific PHP function to be executed within a collection of functions contained with a 'page' without you writing code within the page to broker that interaction.

Answer (score 3):

You could send a GET parameter as part of the AJAX request e.g. `blah.php?func=1`

Then in your PHP file:

```
if ($_GET['func'] == 1) {
    do_something();
}
else {
    do_something_else();
}
```

Or you could use something like CodeIgniter that structures its URL's as controller/function/parameter

Answer (score 0):

no, you can't. but you can pass GET parameters to the URL, and use that URL as a controller.
for example:

```
.load("/ajax_controller.php?action=whatever")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a parameter to PHP script and user switch in script to select which action needs to be done